# Android navigation pattern, deep navigation and up button

Tags: android, android-intent

My sub activity screens all have an "up"-button that runs the following code when touched:

```
...
case android.R.id.home: finnish();break;
...
```

If i usually navigate from activity **A** to activity **C** via **A->B->C**, how can i navigate directly to **C** while maintaining proper up-button functionality (pressing up on activity **C** should take me back to activity **B**)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
startActivity(new Intent(context,B.class));
startActivity(new Intent(context,C.class));
```